# Jquery BBQ, call function instead of hide() or show() for better effects?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-bbq

I'm trying to figure out how to extend the BBQ library to support some basic functionality but I'm finding it impossible to do at the moment. I'm creating a AJAX loading portfolio site and am following this example http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/

I have an isotope grid layout and when clicking an item, i'd like for the grid to fade out and the AJAX content to fade in. I'm using CSS3 transitions for things to be hardware accelerated so the out-of-the-box example isnt doing exactly what id like.

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {


var url = $.param.fragment();


$( 'a.bbq-current' ).removeClass( 'bbq-current' );

// Hide any visible ajax content.            
$( '.site-container' ).children( ':visible').hide();

if ( cache[ url ] ) {
// Since the element is already in the cache, it doesn't need to be
// created, so instead of creating it again, let's just show it!
cache[ url ].show();

} else {
  // Show "loading" content while AJAX content loads.
  $( '#load' ).show();

  // Create container for this url's content and store a reference to it in
  // the cache.
  cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="ajax-item"/>' )

  // Append the content container to the parent container.
  .appendTo( '.site-container' )

  // Load external content via AJAX. Note that in order to keep this
    // example streamlined, only the content in .infobox is shown. You'll
    // want to change this based on your needs.

  .load(url+' .work-detail', function(){
      // Content loaded, hide "loading" content.
      $( '#load' ).hide();
      $('.work-detail').addClass('work-detail-show');
    });
   }
   })

   // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
   // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );

});
```

Ideally Id like to do this for hide/show

```
    $( '.site-container' ).children( ':visible').runSomeFunction();
    cache[ url ].runSomeOtherFunction,''();
```

With these functions being something like

```
    function runSomeFunction() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeOut');//Adds class which changes scale and opacity
    setTimeout(function(){$(this).hide();}, 700);//Removes div
});
```

Currently, I get "runSomeFunction is not a function" errors when trying to do the example above.

Comment: I think the way you are calling .runSomeFunction() is incorrect.

Comment: You need to write it at a jQuery plugin if you want to all it like that. otherwise you need to use jQuery each to loop through the selected objects.